# How do I coalesce NULLs across multiple rows in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, coalesce

I have the following table:

```
Date       |event_number| customer_id1 | customer_age | customer_gender
10/01/2020 |     1      |   abc        |  NULL        |  NULL
10/01/2020 |     2      |   abc        |  NULL        |  male
10/01/2020 |     3      |   abc        |  45          |  NULL
10/01/2020 |     1      |   def        |  30          |  NULL
```

I want to run a SQL query each day to look for new combinations of custom_id1, customer_age, customer_gender.

Output should look like this:

```
query_run_time | customer_id1 | customer_age | customer gender
11/01/2020     | abc          | 45           | male
11/01/2020     | def          | 30           | NULL
```

Query run time is the date the query was run. If the combination (customer_id, custmer_age, customer_gender) is already in the table I don't want to insert the row.

Thanks

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using BigQuery

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the output.  How does "male" get attached to a run time in 2010?

Comment: Apologies, typo in the original question. Updated the examples now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to assign internal row numbers for merge multiple queries, e.g. like this:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(a.customer_id, b.customer_id) as customer_id
     , customer_age
     , customer_gender
  FROM ( 
         SELECT customer_id, customer_age
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY customer_age ) AS row_no
           FROM customer_event
          WHERE customer_age IS NOT NULL
       ) a
  FULL JOIN ( 
         SELECT customer_id, customer_gender
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY customer_gender ) AS row_no
           FROM customer_event
          WHERE customer_gender IS NOT NULL
       ) b ON b.customer_id = a.customer_id
          AND b.row_no = a.row_no
 ORDER BY COALESCE(a.customer_id, b.customer_id)
        , COALESCE(a.row_no, b.row_no)
```

*Schema and Test Data*

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer_event (
  event_number      INT           NOT NULL,
  customer_id       VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
  customer_age      INT,
  customer_gender   VARCHAR(10)
);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO customer_event VALUES
( 1, 'abc', NULL, NULL     ),
( 2, 'abc', NULL, 'male'   ),
( 3, 'abc', 45  , NULL     ),
( 4, 'abc', 50  , 'female' ),
( 5, 'abc', 27  , NULL     ),
( 1, 'def', 30  , NULL     );
```

*Output*

```
customer_id  customer_age  customer_gender
abc          27            female
abc          45            male
abc          50            (null)
def          30            (null)
```

*The above is from testing with **PostgreSQL 9.6** on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/aa9fe/3).*

Answer (score 0):

Use `Window function`

```
SELECT query_run_time, customer_id, MAX(customer_age) customer_age, 
       MAX(customer_gender)customer_gender
FROM tbl
GROUP BY query_run_time, customer_id
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/234d1/3)**

Output

```
query_run_time | customer_id1 | customer_age | customer gender
11/01/2010     | abc          | 45           | male
11/01/2020     | def          | 30           | NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you really want is the most recent value for each column.  Here is one method:

```
select date, customerid1,
       array_agg(customer_age ignore nulls order by event_number desc limit 1)[safe_ordinal(1) as age,
       array_agg(customer_gender ignore nulls order by event_number desc limit 1)[safe_ordinal(1) as gender
from t
group by date, customerid1;
```